# Next Js - Providers/getProviders() - FetchError - next build

Tags: javascript, build, environment-variables, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to build my application next js.
I use providers with next-auth.
It works fine when I use npm run dev.
But when I use npm run build I get this:
[image: error screenshot]

However, I use the variable NEXTAUTH_URL = localhost: 3000 in a .env.local

The error appears when I have "getProviders ()" in a file like this:

```js
import {getProviders, useSession} from 'next-auth/client'
import Layout from "../components/layout";


export default function Page({providers}) {
    const [session, loading] = useSession()

    return (
        <Layout providers={providers}>Page index</Layout>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const providers = await getProviders()

    return {
        props: {providers}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think same probrem this.
[ECONNREFUSED during 'next build'. Works fine with 'next dev'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452675/econnrefused-during-next-build-works-fine-with-next-dev)

It is working.

```
import {getProviders, useSession} from 'next-auth/client'
import Layout from "../components/layout";


export default function Page() {
    const [session, loading] = useSession()
    const [providers, setProviders] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const res = await getProviders();
        setProviders(res);
      })();
    }, []);


    return (
        <Layout providers={providers}>Page index</Layout>
    )
}
```